# Horizontally align then stack columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I horizontally align two columns at col-sm but stack them vertically at col-xs?

I currently have:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"> 
    <div class="row"> 
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">Content</div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">Content</div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Content</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">Content</div>
</div>
```

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/u6mMtQvyzX

**For Claire :**

*You don't need this `row` divs...*

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12"> 
    <!-- <div class="row"> -->     
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">Content</div> 
    <!-- </div> -->  
    <!-- <div class="row">  -->  
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">Content</div> 
    <!--  </div>   -->   
</div>
```

Comment: Was working on it too - here's a bootply with colors to illustrate as well http://www.bootply.com/eYw4rPdx1a

Comment: Sorry, my post posted without me finishing it!

Comment: My code is: <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">Content</div>
    </div>
    </div>

The content just keeps stacking, even at col-sm size, where I would have thought the two 6's would have aligned?

Comment: @Claire destress, just have to edit your question (coucou ^^)

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you!! I fixed it temporarily and then accidentally wrote over the code so I knew it was possible, I just looked at it too ling. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Claire don't forget to accept the answer (at left of the answer) and upvote the comment of our dear Dan please...